# Plugins missing in front end but appear in backend FTP

Tags: plugins

So, I'm working with the Advanced Access Manager and then the W3 Total Cache plugins and all of a sudden WHOOPS, there's a problem.

First last night: After setting up W3 Total Cache, and then playing with it a bit, I broke the site.  I couldn't go to my wp-admin page to login. All it would do was complain about lines in the pluggable.php & wp-login.php.

Now today: So I'm back at it after a good break hoping to be able to fix it with fresh eyes. Great! The pluggable.php error has been fixed. Now in the process of trying to install w3 total cache again, it's randomly complaining about some lines in wp-login.php so I replace my newer wp-login.php file with an older one from a back up and it's fine, however now after some testing and renaming the plugin folder in FTP something different and then back to plugins it's not actually activating ANY plugins and I have no active plugins in my wordpress plugins section...but they are all there in my FTP.

The older wp-login.phph file is of the same site, same login admin credentials and same login info. So now why, as an administrator, I can see any plugins on the front end when they are ALL there in the FTP back end?

Any suggestion as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The path of the plugins directory might have been changed. To be sure, you can double check the [WP_PLUGIN_DIR](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants) constant. For example:

```
print_r( WP_PLUGIN_DIR );
```